# Redirecting to another page meta tag

Tags: html, redirect, meta-tags

If I want to redirect to another page in my HTML file, do in have to place the meta tag in the `head` or can I place it at the top of the file before the DOCTYPE? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't place a `meta` tag above the DOCTYPE. The DOCTYPE must always be the first element in an HTML document, and `meta` tags must only be placed in the `head`.

> Documents must consist of the following parts, in the given order:
>
> - Optionally, a single "BOM" (U+FEFF) character.
> - Any number of comments and space characters.
> - A DOCTYPE.
> - Any number of comments and space characters.
> - The root element, in the form of an html element.
> - Any number of comments and space characters.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#writing

For purposes of this question, the spec says that a document must start with a DOCTYPE and be followed by a root `html` element. While a `meta` tag might still work, there is no guarantee of it doing so today and continuing to do so in the future.

Answer (score 1):

W3C deprecates the use it, but they do offer an example on [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#meta-element):

```
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Don't use this!</TITLE>
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;http://www.example.com/newpage">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <P>If your browser supports Refresh, you'll be transported to our
    <A href="http://www.example.com/newpage">new site</A>
    in 5 seconds, otherwise, select the link manually.
</BODY>
```

Comment: Please refrain from linking to w3schools, which is widely disliked across StackOverflow (see http://w3fools.com for the reasons why). You might have linked to a page that contains correct information, but the site has a lot of incorrect and misleading information - and linking to w3schools in any way gives it credibility it does **not** deserve. (If you use Google Search, and you have a Google account, you can [easily block results](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210386) from w3schools)

Answer (score 1):

The meta tag has to be inside the `<head></head>` section. You can not add anything before `<!DOCTYPE html>`

[**Here is detailed description of DOCTYPE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa218654%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: You might want to pick a better link...the article is 8 years old, written around FrontPage, and outdated/wrong in several areas.

Answer (score 0):

GIYF: [H76: Using meta refresh to create an instant client-side redirect](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76)

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the following line in the **head** section of your HTML page, replacing http:example.com/ with the actual web page to which you want to redirect your viewers:

> < meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://example.com/" />

Here is an example with the correct line inserted in a typical HTML page. Note that it comes above the title tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://example.com" />
<title>Page Moved</title>
</head>
<body>
This page has moved. Click <a href="http://www.example.com">here</a> to go to the new page.
</body>
</html>
```