# Set default homepage in Azure web pages - Continuous Delivery to Github repository

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I need help setting a homepage for a web app that is hosted on Azure. I can get to the site using my-site.azurewebsites.net/Websites-UI/index.html. How/where can I change settings in Azure to point to this index.html file without specifying the folder? (i.e., when a user browses to my-site.azurewebsites.net, it redirects to index.html in the Website-UI folder)

I have a github repository that has the Websites-UI folder that contains index.html and css files.

I am new to web development and Azure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do  you only need your site to redirect to /Websites-UI/index.html when a user arrives at /index.html? If so, you could make an empty /index.html page with a meta tag in its head section, redirecting the user to your other index.html as described e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46251195/5403693.

Comment: I put the index.html file into the root directory, so I don't have that issue anymore... I am now getting the error that "You do not have permission to view this directory or page".

Answer (score 0):

According to your original requirement, you just need to change the value of virtual directory to **site\wwwroot\Websites-UI** in application settings tab in your Azure portal.

Here's the reference>[Direct default URL to a custom directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#direct-default-url-to-a-custom-directory)